# Asp include and Jsp include

Tags: java, jsp, asp-classic

I quote from http://www.valtara.com/csc123/whitepaper/aspbestpractices.htm

```
For all server side notations e.g. #INCLUDE are processed before any of the
script on the page, hence the following code will not have the results one 
might expect: 

If blnLogedIn Then
%><!-- #INCLUDE FILE='IsCust.Asp' --><%
 Else
%><!-- #INCLUDE FILE='DoLogin.Asp' --><%
 End If

Both files are included and then the script is processed!
```

This does not happen same with java and jsp, from this example:

```
index.jsp

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%

        int test = 2;
        if(test == 1){
            %> <jsp:include page="test1.jsp" /> <%
        }else{
            %> <jsp:include page="test2.jsp" /> <%
        }

    %>
 </body>
</html>
```

Content of the jsp includes:

```
test1.jsp

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <h1>Hello Test1!</h1>

<%
System.out.println("Im in test1");
%>

test2.jsp

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <h1>Hello Test2!</h1>

<%
System.out.println("Im in test2");
%>
```

When running the project the result is `Hello Test2!` and the question is: why? Weren't both files suposed to be included? How does java act to includes in difference to asp?

Comment: No, both files are not supposed to be included. Which `jsp:include` tag will execute depends on the `if condition` being evaluated to true. In your case `test = 2`, which results in execution of `else` part. Hence, `test2.jsp` page is included.

Comment: It's based on the language you use that evaluates first.

Comment: That's because in asp, INCLUDEs are replaced with actual file's code at first, before executing any code.